# Showing/Hiding windows iPhone Dev

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

In my iPhone app I am developing, I have defined two windows:

```
@interface The_NoteAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
 IBOutlet UIWindow *newNoteWindow;
 IBOutlet UIWindow *homeWindow;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *newNoteWindow;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *homeWindow;
```

and they are linked correctly in IB - but how do I show/hide these windows?
     `[homeWindow makeKeyAndVisible];` works in `appDidFinishLaunching` but when I try `[newNoteWindow makeKeyAndVisible];` again to open the other window (on a button touch event) in front of the other, the app freezes.
I know this is a very n00by question but please help me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost every instance, you don't want to have multiple instances of `UIWindow`. Your application has its own window, and from there, you deal with views. For what you're trying to do (as far as I can tell from your variable names), it would make sense to use a `UINavigationController`. Then write a `UITableViewController` subclass for your home view, and a `UIViewController` subclass for your notes view.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this wasn't the normal approach. The usual "currency" is the view. Then you can swap views by adding and removing them as subviews to your main view. [self.view addSubView:otherview]

Also look at whether you should be using viewControllers for each thing you want to display, and making use of either the navigationController stack, or displayModalView.